# Type error while trying local data storage, how to initiaise my Website?

Tags: javascript, html, scope, initialization, local-storage

I'm relatively new to Web Development and deploying my first Web App (To-Do-List) right now, you can have a look at it https://peaceful-stream-48694.herokuapp.com/.

Now I want to add HTML local storage to save the To-Do's, and i get thrown a type error (cannot read property of nullof my To-Do's error) when initializing the Website.
I know that I either have to set the array to zero when there is no items from the storage, or load them into the array in case there is (which already worked), however i can't figure out how to do it when there is nothing in storage.

I guess it is a matter of scope, but I just don't know how to solve it. Here is the piece of code that stores and loads the data:

```
function saveList() {
      let str = JSON.stringify(toDoList);
      localStorage.setItem("todoList", str );
    }


    function loadList() {
      if (toDoList == null) {
          toDoList = [];
      } else {
          let str = localStorage.getItem("todoList")
          toDoList = JSON.parse(str);
          displayList()
      }
    }

    function displayList() {
    if (toDoList != null) {
     for(i=0; i < toDoList.length; i++) {
        htmlInsert ='<div id="' + toDoList[i].id + '" class="newItem"> <input type="checkbox"> <p>' + toDoList[i].toDo +'</p> <button type="button" class="deleteButton">DELETE</button></div>';
        list = document.getElementById("itemsList");
        list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", htmlInsert);
        SetupEventListener();
          }
        }
      }


    loadList()
```

The To-Do array is globally defined at the beginning:
`let toDoList = [];`

I appreciate any help.
Thanks a lot and sorry if this is messy, didn't know how to make this clearer.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize `let toDoList = []`, then the first thing you do (in loadList()) is test `if (toDoList == null)`. This condition will never be met.

I think your loadList function should look like this :

```
function loadList() {
     let str = localStorage.getItem("todoList"); // can be null
     toDoList = str ? JSON.parse(str) : [];
     displayList();
}
```

Then in `displayList()` you can remove `if (toDoList != null)` because this condition will always be met (todoList will never be null because it is always initialized as an array)

Comment: Yes! I see my mistake, thank you so much! However, i'm facing another problem that doesnt make much sense to me: When i run the for loop in displayList, it saves all the elemts properly in the storage, but when reloading them the second item or toDoList[1] disappears from the UI but is still in the stored toDoList array?

Comment: Glad I could help! However, if you have another problem, please create another question.